# Loading Vue components using laravel-mix in Code Igniter 3 application

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I am trying to load Vue 3 components inside a legacy Code Igniter 3 application using laravel-mix.

My folder structure is the following:

```
application
   components
      App.vue
   views
      layout.php
assets
   src
      app.js
      app.scss
   package.json
   package-lock.json
   webpack.mix.js
```

package.json:

```
    {
       "name": "assets",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "description": "",
       "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
     },
     "keywords": [],
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC",
     "devDependencies": {
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.68.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vue": "^3.3.4",
        "vue-loader": "^16.2.0",
        "webpack": "^5.88.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
     }
    }
```

app.js:

```
    import {createApp} from 'vue';
    import App from '../../application/components/App.vue';
    
    createApp(App).mount('#vueapp');
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
    let mix = require('laravel-mix');
    
    mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist/').vue().setPublicPath('dist');
    mix.sass('src/app.scss', 'dist/').setPublicPath('dist');
```

App.vue:

```
    <template>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

              <div class="card-body">
                I'm an example component!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
      }
    }
    </script>
```

layout.php:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="vueapp"></div>
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>/assets/dist/app.js"></script> 
    </body>
```

I run `npm run watch` to build webpack but I receive this error:

```
ERROR in ../application/components/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=1ab0ca96 (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-load
er/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!../application/components/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=1ab0ca96) 1:0-173
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\My Web Sites\myapp\application\components'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?
```

Looking into it, it seems like the Vue package is visible inside app.js but not inside App.vue. Am I missing a step in my webpack mix config? Do I have to somehow include my components folder in the config?